# using info to search for an 'item'

Tags: linux, info

so I have this handy little function:

`zhelp() { man zshall | less -p "^       $1" }`

... but it's time I moved to 'info' and I trust there's a simple option to search for some ... not just a string ... but a ... sorry, I don't know the jargon ... but an 'entry' or 'heading' or 'item'. As above, in 'man' these always have seven spaces after the beginning of a line then the name of the 'item'.  I looked at 'info info' but you hafta already know the jargon to make any sense of it.  I'll bet this is easy if you already know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried:

```
% info zshall mapfile
```

... when what's needed is:

```
% info zsh mapfile
```

... and it works fine :-)